# Poincare duality

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, differential-forms, poincare-duality

\section{Список литературы}

Let $ M $ be a smooth and compact manifold with boundary $\partial M = X \times F $ on which the structure of a smooth locally trivial bundle $$ \pi: \partial M \longrightarrow X $$
where the $ X $  and the fiber $ F $ are smooth compact manifolds without boundary. Consider the equivalence relation on the set M
\begin{equation}
z \sim z^{\prime} \Longleftrightarrow z = z^{\prime} \quad \text {or} \quad (z, z^ {\prime} \in \partial M \quad \text{and} \quad \pi(z) = \pi (z^{\prime})).
\end{equation}
We define the topological space $ N = M / \sim $ as the quotient space of the manifold M with respect to the equivalence relation above.
Informally speaking, $ N $ is obtained from $ M $ (by contracting the fibers of the bundle $ \pi $ to points). The set $ N $ is a disjoint union $ N = X \sqcup M^{\circ} $ of the manifold $ X $ and the interior  $ M^{\circ} $ of $ M $. The natural projection of $$ p: M \longrightarrow N $$ coincides with the identity map on $ M ^ {\circ} $ and the projection $ \pi $ on $ \partial M $.
So the manifold $N$ can be not smooth sometimes.
How to define the map $I : H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)\longrightarrow H_{k}(N)$ when $F$ is not a singleton?

Comment: As it stands, the answer is ... You don't.

Comment: Try using the de Rham theorem: $H^*_{dR}(M) \cong H_{sing}^*(M;\mathbb{R})$

Comment: So there's no map between them , even in terms of integral?

Comment: Dear william, I tried but it doesnt work. I have been sitting down on that problem longtime. Could you try to write something down for me please

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking for. For one thing, how are $M$ and $N$ supposed to be related? Are they just two random manifolds? Furthermore, for a non-smooth manifold the de Rham cohomology groups aren't defined so you would need to be more specific about what you mean by "integral" if you want your question to make sense. In singular homology there is the Kronecker pairing between $H^n(N)$ and $H_n(N)$, which is analogous to integration.

Comment: M is a smooth manifold where \partial M = X*F.  pi : \partial M to X.  N is the manifold opened by sending the boundary of M to X. My question is how to define a map from de Rham cohomology of M to the singular of N?

Comment: What do you mean by "X*F"? What is F? Most of us reading your question are likely to be unfamiliar with the problem you're working on, so you should include in the question any information which isn't common knowledge. (Also don't forget to include math tags `$$` so that the LaTeX formats properly)

Comment: Let $ M $ be a smooth and compact manifold with boundary $ \partial M = X \times F $ on which the structure of a smooth locally trivial bundle $$ \pi: \partial M \longrightarrow X $$
where $ X $ - the base  $F$- the fiber are smooth compact manifolds without boundary. By sending $\partial M$ to $X$ we obtained  a new manifold called $N$. This manifold can be not smooth. How to define a map $I : H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)\longrightarrow H_{k}(N)  when N is not smooth

Comment: Dear william, I hope my question is clear now. Any idea, please?

Comment: Yes it's very clear now, thank you! I will think about it and see if I can come up with something, but the question of very well-phrased now.

Comment: What do you mean by "By sending ∂ to  we obtained a new manifold"? You wrote $\partial M= X\times F$. The only natural way to "send" $\partial M$ to $X$ is to use the projection to the first factor. The image, of course, will be $X$. When is $N$ then?

Comment: Hello Dear Moishe Kohan, I reformuled my question. Help please if you can. Am stuck with that problem for longtime now

Comment: N is the manifold we obtain under the equivalence relation. We can $N$ as $$N=M^{\circ}\sqcup X$

Comment: Moishe Kohan. hope you undertand my question. N can be see as the union of X and the interior of  M.

Comment: OK, now the definitions are clear but the question is not. For instance, what if I tell you to use zero map, would you object?   You probably want some naturality properties. However, if $F$ is a singleton, $N=M$, so you are then asking for a natural map $H^{n-k}(M)\to H_k(M)$ (where, probably, $n=\dim(M)$). The Poincare duality gives you $H^{n-k}(M)\to H_k(M, \partial M)$. There are no "natural" maps from that to $H_k(M)$: The natural map goes in the opposite direction.

Comment: Am not about the trivial case, like if $F$ is singleton. I want to define a map when $F$ is not singleton.

Comment: Moishe Kohan, I hope you understand again my question.

Comment: No, it is still as unclear as before. For the question to make sense, you should explain what properties your map should have, otherwise, zero map will always do the job. Voting to close for now.

Comment: Moishe Kohan. it should be a zero map. I'm looking for a map in general case. Not the zero.

Answer (score 0):

I can come up with at least a partial answer, using [the de Rham theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#De_Rham's_theorem) (dR) and [Poincare-Lefschetz duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_duality) (PLD). Note that $X$ is naturally embedded as a subspace of $N$, as the image of $\partial M$ under the quotient map $q\colon M \to N$. Then we have
$$H^{n-k}_{dR}(M) \stackrel{dR}{\cong} H^{n-k}(M;\mathbb{R}) \stackrel{PLD}{\cong} H_k(M,\partial M;\mathbb{R}) \stackrel{q_*}{\to} H_k(N, X; \mathbb{R}).$$

If $H_{k+1}(X) = H_{k-1}(X) = 0$ then $H_k(N,X)\cong H_k(N)$ so we can naturally make a homomorphism which maps to $H_k(N)$, but I'm not sure how to do so in general unless $H_*(X;\mathbb{R})$ vanishes in the right degrees.

Comment: I have tried using the fundamental class of $N$. Since $M$ and $N$  have the same dimension, but am not sure if it's a good definition. Let $[N]=\sum_{j}c_{j} $the fundamental class of $N$. We define the following \begin{eqnarray*}
\mu=\left[N\right]\frown:  H^{n-k}_{dR}(M,\pi) & \longrightarrow & H_{k}(N) \\
\omega & \longmapsto & \sum\limits_{j}\left(\int_{c_{j}\mid_{\Delta^{n-k}}}\omega\right)c_{j}\mid_{\Delta^{k}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: William, how to define the map if $ H_{*}(X,\mathbb{R})$ vanishes  in the right degrees. Could you give an example of definition in that case, please